# @Async EJB method AsyncResult JBoss - java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.ejb.AsyncResult

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am a newbie in JBoss world and currently working on my first program. Therefore, I beg your pardon in advance if my question is trivial. However I still don't know the answer(have already asked in JBoss community and Coderanch), so would be grateful if anybody could give me any advice.

The challenge is to run EJB method asynchronously for further retrieving some information or stopping.

I'm using JBoss AS version 5.0, Eclipse JUNO (plug-ins 3.8.2-4.2.2 )

I'm using AsyncResult class taken from ejb31-api-experimental-3.1.4.jar library. My business logic on server seems to work perfectly, but when the result is to be returned to the client application I receive an exception:

my EJB sample code is:

```
    package org.braman.apps.demo.ejb;  
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;  
    import java.net.*;  
    import java.io.*;  
    import java.util.*;  
    import java.util.concurrent.Future;  
    import javax.ejb.*;  
    import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;  
    import javax.ejb.AsyncResult;  
    import java.io.Serializable;  

    @Stateless  
    @Remote  
    @Asynchronous  
    public class DemoStatelessBean implements DemoStatelessRemote, Serializable {  

        @Override  
        @Asynchronous  
        public Future<String> tn_mainloop() {  

             // my business logic here  

                 return new AsyncResult<String>("HELLO");               
        }  
    }  


Remote interface is:

       package org.braman.apps.demo.ejb;  
        import javax.ejb.Remote;  
        import java.util.concurrent.Future;  
        import javax.ejb.*;  

        @Remote  
        public interface DemoStatelessRemote {  
             public String getDemoWord();  
             @Asynchronous  
             public Future<String> tn_mainloop();  

        }
```

The client application is

```
   public class DemoStatelessClient implements Serializable {  
    /** 
     *  
     */  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  
    {  

     Context context;  

  Properties properties = new Properties();                              properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");  
    properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");  

        properties.put("java.naming.provider.url","localhost:1099");  
        context = new InitialContext(properties);     

        DemoStatelessRemote simpleSession  
       = (DemoStatelessRemote) context.lookup("DemoStatelessBean/remote");  

        System.out.printf(">> %s\n", DemoStatelessRemote.class.getName());  


    try {  
        //Future<String> fut=simpleSession.tn_mainloop();  

        final Future<String> str = simpleSession.tn_mainloop();  
        str.get();  

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  

            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {  

            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (EJBException ejbe) {  
            ejbe.printStackTrace();  
        }  

        }  
    }
```

The method itself works perfectly well (in JBoss console everthying is ok and it really operates ok). But the error occurs during returning the result to the client.
Would be grateful if somebody could help.
Have looked though the Internet, but the only solution that I figured out is about implementation of "Serializable" interface. But AsyncResult is a supplied class.
The jar containing AsyncResult is ejb31-api-experimental-3.1.4.jar has been found in the Internet. Please, help.
Thanks in advance/

The log:

> ```
> Caused by: org.jboss.remoting.InvocationFailureException: Unable to perform invocation; nested exception is:   
>     java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.ejb.AsyncResult  
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.handleException(SocketClientInvoker.java:139)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:886)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:160)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1708)  
>     at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:612)  
>     at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60)
>
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
>
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
>
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:76)
>
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>
>     at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)  
>     at $Proxy4.invoke(Unknown Source)  
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:125)
>
>     ... 2 more  
> Caused by: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.ejb.AsyncResult  
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)  
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)  
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.InvocationResponse.readExternal(InvocationResponse.java:119)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1810)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)  
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888) 
>
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)  
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)  
>     at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:238)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:138)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.read(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:123)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.versionedRead(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:1215)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:845)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:160)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1708)  
>     at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:612)  
>     at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60)
>
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
>
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
>
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:76)
>
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>
>     at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)  
>     at $Proxy4.invoke(Unknown Source)  
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:125)
>
>     at $Proxy3.tn_mainloop(Unknown Source)  
>     at org.braman.apps.demo.ejb.DemoStatelessClient.main(DemoStatelessClient.java:59)
>
>     at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:72)
>
>     ... 12 more  
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.ejb.AsyncResult  
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173) 
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:343)  
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.InvocationResponse.writeExternal(InvocationResponse.java:100)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1438)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1407)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1167) 
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1526)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1491)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1409)
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1167) 
>
>     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:343)  
>     at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.sendObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:120)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.sendObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:95)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableMarshaller.write(SerializableMarshaller.java:120)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.versionedWrite(ServerThread.java:998)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:781)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:695)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:522)
>
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThrea
> ```

d.run(ServerThread.java:230)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you use a very old version of JBoss AS, where @Asynchronous is not supported (@Asynchronous was added in Java EE 6, which supported beginning with JBoss AS 7.x).

To avoid in future this problem you could (in Eclipse) add to your project build path the jar files from the local JBoss in order to see what is supported.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. If I understand correctly there are no problems with annotations(however I admit that the output can have nothing to do with the real cause). I'm using the library ejb31-api-experimental-3.1.4.jar which I have found in the Internet (containing AsyncResult class). Could you, please, clarify which of the standard JBoss 7 libraries does contain AsyncResult class? Thanks.

Comment: The annotations won't work, meaning: because of the annotations no errors will be thrown in JBoss 5.X, but the code will not work as you read in the documentation, because that JBoss version (5.X) does not know/see that annotation and will simply ignore it. But returning a Future (which is not allowed) generates that exception (in JBoss 5.X). That means, you can not test @Async/Feature in JBoss 5.X, and only in JBoss 7.X you can. So replace your JBoss version with the last one.

Comment: After seeing that it works there, don't forget to mark the issue as solved.

Comment: Hope it will help. Another question - is asyc EJB method ivocation a right approach to tackle long-term(theoretically infinite) asynchronous processes? The only alternative that I am aware of is pojo service, but it doesn't suit my task because it works like a singleton bean whereas I am going to implement multiple asynchronous processes.

Comment: It took me some time to struggle through EJB security framework which is required to be used in JBoss 7.1, however the code is working correctly now. Thus, the solution is to migrate the code to JBoss 7. Thanks Andrei I!!!